# SQL compare Registrant Name to a reference table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, pattern-matching

Hi I have two tables within my database, a registrant table with a "Registrant Name" field and other information and a reference / lookup table which contains a column called "Business_Identifier"

The idea is to compare the data in the "Registrant Name" field with the data contained in the "Business_Identifier" column to identify whether the data contained in the "Registrant Name" field is that of a business or an individual

An example would be:

```
Registrant Table:
ID: 1234
Registrant NAme: ABC Ltd


Lookup Table:
ID:1,2,3                      
Business_Identifier: ltd,PLC,LLC
```

I am looking to create a stored procedure which would carry out some form of pattern matching taking the lookup table data and seeing if any of it appears in the "Registrant Name" field, thereby identifying the record as a business.

I created a script which carrys out pattern matching on a static list, see an example below, but I need to turn the static list into a table so that it can be updated

Current Script:

```
With Test as (
SELECT *    
  FROM [Registrant_Table]
  where (patindex('%[0-9]%',UPPER([Registrant name])) > 0
     or patindex('%null%',UPPER([Registrant name])) > 0
     or patindex('%n/a%',UPPER([Registrant name])) > 0     
     or patindex('na',UPPER([Registrant name])) > 0
     or patindex('%LTD%',UPPER([Registrant name])) > 0
     or patindex('%None%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%unknown%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Ltd%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%ltd%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%LLC%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%LLc%',[Registrant name]) > 0     
     or patindex('%LLP%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%LLp%',[Registrant name]) > 0       
     or patindex('%llp%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Limited%',[Registrant name]) > 0          
     or patindex('%LIMITED%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Limi%',[Registrant name]) > 0 
     or patindex('%Company%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Tele%',[Registrant name]COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) > 0  
     or patindex('%Trade%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Host%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     or patindex('%Domain%',[Registrant name]) > 0
     )

select * 
Into [Registrant_Table_Business]
from Test
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup table defines bit columns for `upper` and `collation`, you might use:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM [Registrant_Table] r
 CROSS JOIN [PatternLookup] l
 WHERE patindex('%' + l.Pattern + '%', 
        case when l.IsUpper = 1
             then case when l.IsLatin1_General_CS_AI = 1 
                  then upper (r.[Registrant name]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
                  else upper (r.[Registrant name]) 
                  end
             else case when l.IsLatin1_General_CS_AI = 1 
                       then r.[Registrant name]  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
                       else r.[Registrant name]
                  end
        end) > 0
```

**UPDATE:** create table for patterns:

```
create table PatternLookup
(
  PatternLookupID int identity primary key,
  Pattern nvarchar(100) not null,
  IsUpper bit default 0 not null,
  IsLatin1_General_CS_AI bit default 0 not null
)
```

And few inserts:

```
   insert into PatternLookup (Pattern, isUpper, IsLatin1_General_CS_AI) values
          ('LTD', 1, 0),   -- This pattern asks for uppercased [Registrant name]
          ('Tele', 0, 1),  -- This one needs registrant in different collation
          ('Company', 0, 0)-- And this one is as-is
```

Comment: Hi @Nikola, I think your on the right lines, I looked at your query and tried to run it, but got the following errors: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'IsUpper'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'IsLatin1_General_CS_AI'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'IsLatin1_General_CS_AI'.

Comment: @MarkSouthwell Oh, I proposed to you to add these two columns to lookup table to be able to control how pattern matching should be done; I've noticed that sometimes you are comparing Upper([Registrant name]) and in one instance you are changing collation.